# Is an LED fixture with no ground wire safe and legal?

Tags: wiring

I'm installing a new Hampton Bay LED surface mount light. Coming out of the entirely plastic casing are only two wires--one black and one white.  There is no grounding wire.  Is this ok?  I'm in Saskatchewan.

Comment: Model number of the new light?

Comment: For all sorts of wall-powered appliances, check the device and packaging for a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory mark (UL, CSA, Intertek/ETL, etc.). If it's got one, a lab examined it and it's very likely safe.

Answer (score 3):

The plastic casing is a clue that there may be no need for a ground wire and in fact nothing that a ground wire could connect to.   The brand name indicates you bought it from a (certain) retail store so it probably has appropriate electrical certifications for your location.  Look at the labelling, if it actually has those certifications, you have nothing to worry about.  Not sure what those are in Saskatchewan, CSA mabye?

Comment: with disposable fixtures, there's no risk of shock from touching the bulb socket sleeve when wired with hot and neutral reversed.

Answer (score 2):

If the appliance is double insulated then that's fine.  If you have a ground wire, leave it safely tucked away.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two twin and earth cables to connect to the LED light we need to maintain the earth continuity. If no terminal is provided a simple solution is to twist the earth wires together and ensure they are insulated from L and N. I do not know if this is illegal! I found this situation in UK recently because original LED fixture is currently unavailable and replacements come without an Earth terminal!